# background-image in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

When I do inspect element on [my wordpress page](http://chuaquanam.ca/wordpress/) on the left of my screen I have this code,

```
<header class="main-header" role="banner">
```

on the right of my screen I have this code

```
background-image: url('http://chuaquanam.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/cropped-TopMenu11.jpg');
```

Can someone help me in what *.css file the background-image code is located? I looked at all css files like style.css but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the header element shows that the CSS for header.main-header is inline. This means, it is generated by WP and embedded into the page, not into a CSS file. Once generated, you can see the code by viewing the source of your blog page:

```
<style type="text/css">
      header.main-header
      {
         background-image: url('http://chuaquanam.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/cropped-TopMenu11.jpg');
         width: 980px;
         height: 200px;
      }
```

.. which is on line 67 onwards.

The way for you to change your background-image is via the WP menu, if you select Appearance > Header, you can upload a new image, which will populate the width and height based on the image you upload.

If you want to edit styling other than these properties (like positioning, floating, etc.,) you can find the other header.main-header styling in style.css, line 253 onwards.